# Is there any easy proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem?

Tags: general-topology, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am taking a course in game theory. For proving the Nash equilibrium we require  Brouwer's fixed point theorem. But I have not taken a topology course so I am finding the proof difficult to understand. You may explain the same Brouwer's in little easy way.

Comment: There's an easy proof based on [Sperner's lemma](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture03.pdf)

Comment: Which proof do you find difficult to understand?

Answer (score 8):

Of course "easy" has a large degree of subjectivity to it.  But there is a famous proof due to Emanuel Sperner that was (and still is) striking for minimizing the amount of topology needed.

[These](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture03.pdf) course notes of Jacob Fox give an exposition using Sperner's Lemma.  The document starts from scratch and proves Brouwer's Theorem (for all $n$) in just under 2.5 pages.

Answer (score 5):

I think so.  Hirsch's proof, which is in Guillemin and Pollack.

It goes (something like)  this:

Suppose $p:D^2\to D^2$ doesn't have a fixed point.  Define $r:D^2\to S^1$ by $r(x)$ is the point on the segment from $x$ to $p(x)$ on $S^1$.  $r$ would be a retraction of the disk onto the circle.  This is impossible.

Comment: Though this proof might be geometrically intuitive, regular point theorem, Sard's theorem and classification of $1$-manifold are not easy at all.

Comment: Yes.  I'm assuming you know they have different homology, say.

Answer (score 4):

Aigner gives an elementary proof for the case $n = 2$ in *[Proofs from the BOOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK)*.

But if I remember correctly you need Brouwer's fixed point theorem for arbitrary $n$ in the proof of Nash.

saulspatz has a source for this (and the general case) in his comment to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at [John Milnor's take](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~karatson/hairy-ball.pdf). His methods are all quite elementary (the most difficult prerequisite needed here is the well-known-but-rarely-proved [change of variables theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)). However, in my opinion this proof is indeed quite mysterious and John himself seems to agree with that.

Answer (score 1):

***Topological Spaces** From Distance To Nighborhood* by Gerard Buskes and Arnoud van Rooij provide a nice 'intuitive proof' (Section~4.21). It is not exact, but it has plenty of diagrams and explanations.